# One ipcMain.on() works in the same file while the other doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipcmain

I am developing an app using Electron and vue.

I use [this solution](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) to communicate between main and render, so I have three files, `preload.js` , main and renderer.

```js
// preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        // whitelist channels
        let validChannels = ["msgbox", "loadall", "savekv", "saveall"];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    }
});
```

```js
// main
const { ipcMain, dialog } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on("msgbox", (event, args) => dialog.showMessageBox({ message: args }))
ipcMain.on("saveall", (event, config) => dialog.showMessageBox({ message: config }))
```

```js
// renderer
test() {
  window.api.send("saveall", "hahaha");  // <- does not work
  window.api.send("msgbox", "haha");     // <- work
}
```

However, in render file, `window.api.send("msgbox", "haha");` works while `window.api.send("saveall", "hahaha");` does not.

Electron version 13.6.6
macOS Monterey 12.1

Answer (score 0):

In theory, there is no reason why both dialog boxes should not show at the same time (`hahaha` then `haha`).

In reality, I noticed that 50% of the time, only one of the two dialog boxes would show when initially clicking the `button`. It was random as to which dialog box would show when only one was displayed. I suspect this may have something to do Javascript's inner workings of the stack and event loop.

To have both dialog boxes show all the time, delaying the display of the second dialog box by only 10ms would work 100% of the time. Additionally, the order of the dialog boxes would always be guaranteed. IE: `hahaha` then `haha`.

The above results were tested on both Electron v13.6.6 and Electron v18.1.0 (Windows 10) with the below code.

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'api', {
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ["msgbox", "loadall", "savekv", "saveall"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require('path');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('msgbox', (event, args) => {
    console.log(args); // Testing
    electronDialog.showMessageBox({message: args} )
});

electronIpcMain.on('saveall', (event, config) => {
    console.log(config); // Testing
    electronDialog.showMessageBox({message: config} )
});
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="button">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementeById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Test 1 - Inconsistent results
            window.api.send("saveall", "hahaha");
            window.api.send("msgbox", "haha");

            // Test 2 - Consistent results
            // window.api.send("saveall", "hahaha");
            // setTimeout(() => { window.api.send("msgbox", "haha"); }, 10);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```